# How do I delay the parameter hintbox appearance in vscode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Whenever I hover over a function as such in `VScode`, I get the parameter hint box which would appear within a second as such:

[image]

I want to add a delay of say 3 seconds for the box appearance, how can that be done?